# Regular expression to not match the logs with unreadable characters in syslog-ng

Tags: regex, syslog-ng

I am getting these kind of lines with other relevant log lines in the logs

```
/M��P���������
M�bM���������
�?�@���������
�S��T���������
��bM���������
E��F���������
22��O���������
��9���������
_������������
```

These lines are non-readable so I want to exclude these all log lines.

Sample log lines looks like

`Aug 18,etc message...`

So basically what I am trying to achieve is something like below:

```
{netmask(192.168.0.1/32) and not(match("\W+))};
```

Comment: The pattern for a non-letter at the start of the string is `^[^A-Za-z]` or `^\P{L}` or `^[^[:alpha:]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exclude lines with non-ascii characters, if that's what you want.

Could look like this (I guess):

```
{netmask(192.168.0.1/32) and not(match('[\x80-\xff]'))};
```

Note: I used single `'` quotes in this example.
If you use `"` double-quotes, you have to use `\\` instead of `\`.